# Can't send data to client using winsock2.lib

Tags: c++, sockets

We have tcp/ip application project and using winsock2.lib in our source code, server and client functions are below:

server:

```
#undef UNICODE
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
using namespace::std;



int server()
{
    string SERVER_ADDRESS= "172.17.11.138";
    int PORT_NUMBER = 27015;

    sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=htons(PORT_NUMBER);
    server.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=inet_addr(&SERVER_ADDRESS[0]);


    WSADATA wsaData;
        int iResult;
    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

   // Initialize Winsock
       iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
       if (iResult != 0) {
       printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
       return 1;
    }
    int iSendResult;
char recvbuf[256];
int recvbuflen = 256;

// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Setup the TCP listening socket
iResult = bind( ListenSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server));
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// No longer need server socket
closesocket(ListenSocket);

// Echo the buffer back to the sender
iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0 );
if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
}
```

client:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


int client()
{
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
string SERVER_ADDRESS= "172.17.11.138";

char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
char recvbuf[256];
int PORT_NUMBER = 27015;
int iResult;

sockaddr_in server;
server.sin_family=AF_INET;
server.sin_port=htons(PORT_NUMBER);
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=inet_addr(&SERVER_ADDRESS[0]);
// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

iResult = connect( ConnectSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server));
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
    }

 iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, 256, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 )
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if ( iResult == 0 )
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
```

we compiled those codes above and, server and client can connect to each other(checked it with tcpview application) but, we wanted to sent data from server to client, winsock2 return error 10057(if we close the listen socket the error will be 10038) also, send function returned -1.

Comment: First, you should avoid calling _any_ winsock function before `WSAStartup()`, This includes `htons()` and `inet_addr()`. secondly, error 10057 is `WSAENOTCONN`

Answer (score 0):

Well, one issue is, what are you sending from your server?  This code:

```
iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0 );
```

seems to be sending `iResult` bytes (which is 0 from last `listen` call) of an uninitialized buffer `recvbuf`.  The client seems to have a `sendbuf` which isn't used anywhere.  Seems like a few bugs to clean up and you'll be functioning...